# How can i use package management in NodeJS Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions

I'm trying to build this sample project as a Azure Function and it requires some packages https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Nodejs-Microsoft-Graph-App-only

I can see that I can use packet management in NodeJS Azure Functions using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-reference/#nodejavascript-api

I tried to use this

```
var request = require('request');
```

This statement

```
You can include packages in your function directory (i.e. via npm install) and then import them to your function in the usual ways (i.e. via require('packagename'))
```

So I created a project.json with this in it like the C# Azure Function uses:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "chalk": "^1.1.1",
        "q": "^1.4.1",
        "request": "^2.67.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and get this error

```
2016-04-06T19:49:42.026 Exception while executing function: Functions.MicrosoftGraphWebHookNode. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. Error: Cannot find module 'request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\MicrosoftGraphWebHookNode\index.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17).
```

Should the project.json work?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can include your `package.json` in you function directory and run `npm install` as you normally would with Node.js projects using Kudu or the Console in the Azure portal.

More information can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#dependency-management

Comment: Thank you. Totally makes sense now that would be how this hangs together.

Comment: Updated link for package management: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management

Comment: Here are the steps to do this in Kudu: open "https://<your function app>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole" in the browser; "cd site\wwwroot\<your function>"; "npm install".

Comment: npm install is taking a lot of time to install the packages in Azure function console. I can see node_modules folder created, but all the packages are under **.staging** folder

Comment: @Fabio is it possible to install them at the function-app level instead of function level? Are there any performance benefits of using an Azure Artifact feed?

Comment: Nevermind I went through the documentation -- I'm not used to having good documentation. When there's no indian tutorials or medium articles written by fresh bootcamp <graduates> I tend to assume that the technology is just not that popular instead of assuming the documentation is good enough on its own.

Answer (score -1):

I did a similar thing and SMTP worked without using SendGrid. 
Below is my code for azure function.

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {

let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: '',
    port: 2525,
    auth: {
       user: '',
       pass: ''
    }
});


const message = {
    from: '', // Sender address
    to: '',         // List of recipients
    subject: '', // Subject line
    text: '' // Plain text body
};

transport.sendMail(message, function(err, info) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(info);
    }
});

};
```