# Azure Functions - Import Custom Node Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm experimenting with Azure Functions. I'm trying to use a third-party Node module in my function. However, I've been unable to figure out how to import it.

```
{
  "id": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee",
  "requestId": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "messsage": "Exception while executing function: Functions.analyze -> Error: Cannot find module 'moment'\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename .."
}
```

I'm just trying to import the moment.js Node library. I was unable to find any documentation around this scenario though.

Does anyone know how to import a third-party module into Azure Functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i use package management in NodeJS Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461247/how-can-i-use-package-management-in-nodejs-azure-functions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In your function app in the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com), click **Platform features** and **Advanced tools (Kudu)**.

[image]

2. `cd` into your function directory via **Debug console** (CMD or PowerShell) and run the command: `npm install moment`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is now out of date.  Instead, go to Advanced Tools (Kudo) -> Bash -> cd site/wwwroot -> npm i package

Answer (score 0):

You also can setup it with **VsCode**:

1. **Azure Functions: Create Function...**
2. Select **JavaScript**
3. Select **HTTP trigger**
4. Now you can install dependencies with you local `NodeJS`:
   [image]

5.You can deploy your function with the extension interface:

[image]