# Remove HTML markup from text in Azure Function app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app

I am writing a simple Azure Function app that should receive a string containing HTML markup remove the HTML tags and return the "sanitized" text.

The code would be really simple, like

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    if (req.body) {
        context.res = {
            body: req.body.replace(... something)
        };
    }
};
```

As far as I can see on SO, using RegEx to do this is a big NO-GO, but the other solutions I can find to this are all based on the DOM (working on the `document`object, like adding a DIV with the `req.body` contents in it and getting the clean text from that.

But in my Azure function, the DOM is not available to me (since there is no browser executing the request.

So what are my options?

Comment: Can you import node.js modules? There are several out there that can be used to parse the DOM - [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) comes to mind, although I'm sure there are others.

Comment: @Kryten but if the DOM is not available, will it help?

Comment: Why not just install a library like sanitize-html or striptags? Azure functions allow that...

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge oh ... did not know that. I found this on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169066/azure-functions-import-custom-node-module . Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of others coming across this, like Carlos and Kryten mentioned, you could use one of the many `npm` modules available for sanitizing text.

As for adding these dependencies (refer [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#dependency-management)), you could either

1. When working locally, just `npm install` what you need and when using `func` to deploy, it will include `node_modules` too. This would help with cold starts since it [runs the package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package) as is. The same applies when using [`docker`-based deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image) too with the default `Dockerfile`.
2. Using Kudu as mentioned in the [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169066/azure-functions-import-custom-node-module) you've shared. **But** would not recommended this since its something you'll always have to do on changes in dependencies.