# Cannot perform http request with http module nodejs azure function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, http, azure-functions

I am trying to make a http request with node module `http` on an azure function with javascript and for some reason `http.request` is not receiving data(no error printed its like the requested is blocked). There is anything wrong with azure configuration or the code?Am i missing something really obvious?

> Code is running fine on local js file

`context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);` 
printed as expected but `context.log("SUCCESS", JSON.parse(data));` not printed at all.

Also tryed different libraries (request, axios) with no success

```
    module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
        var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

        if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
        {
            context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
        }
        context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);  

        const http = require('http');
        http.get('http://myAPIurl', (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
          context.log("SUCCESS", JSON.parse(data));
        });

      }).on("error", (err) => {
      context.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
      });

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing async and callbacks, your function execution is likely returning before your callback gets called. If you change your code to be awaitable I think you should start seeing the results you expect.

Comment: @nelak I removed async and still not working also tryed to put await on http without success, maybe you have a minimal working example that i can work with?

Comment: Can you check that the `http` module is part of your dependencies? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461247/how-can-i-use-package-management-in-nodejs-azure-functions

Comment: yes http module loaded properly

Comment: Are you using function runtime version 1 or 2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions)?

Comment: version 2 '''''

Comment: Are you using the cloud editor or uploading through Visual Studio/VS Code?

Comment: the cloud editor

Answer (score 8):

I rewrote your code using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). It has support for async/await out of the box, and simplifies a lot of the code to function as your would expect since it makes asynchronous code perform like synchronous code.

I think the main issue you may have been running into it that everything in JavaScript is async. As a result, the Azure Function runtime was exiting before your async function finished since it didn't block like synchronous code would when making the HTTP request. If you want to use callbacks, you need to call `context.done()` inside your callback function so the Azure Function doesn't exit before the callback is completed. By using async/await, you can guarantee that your code will block on the HTTP request until it receives a response or timeout. In the example below, Axios will return a response object that includes data as an element. I'm extracting data with a deconstruction operation, which allows me to log `data`.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const url = 'https://google.com';

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    context.log(data);
    // do something with the data
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    context.log(err);
    // do something with the error
  }

  context.done();
}
```

**To Install a Package on an Azure Function**

1. Go to the Azure Portal; select your Azure Function App
2. Select `Platform Features`. Then `Advanced Tools (Kudu)` under **Development Tools**
3. Using the file explorer, navigate to `site/wwwroot/`. You should see a `package.json` file in there, and several folders each with the name of your functions.
4. From that directory, run `npm install --save axios`
5. To confirm it worked, edit your `package.json` with the pencil icon. `axios` should be listed under `dependencies` json element

Comment: tested this too and not works check the comment on the above answer

Comment: Did you run `npm install --save axios`? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: dont have the stack trace but contex.log(axios) prints the library as it should

Comment: check my answer this is really weird

Comment: The code above works as-is if you copy and paste into a new Azure timer function. I did have to go to the diagnostics console to install Axios.

Comment: I updated the answer to explain how to install packages with npm and kudu

Answer (score 1):

I've kept your code callback based.
I removed the `async` moniker from the definition and added a call to `context.done` (this signals the functions host when your function has ended) in your `resp.end` handler

```
module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

    if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    }
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);  

    const https = require('https');
    https.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LearnWebCode/json example/master/animals-1.json', (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    resp.on('end', () => {
      context.log("SUCCESS", JSON.parse(data));
      context.done(null, data);
    });

  }).on("error", (err) => {
    context.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
  });

}
```

Another option would be to keep the function as `async` but you'd need to replace the callbacks with `promise` based calls. In some scenarios this can be achieved by wrapping them using [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) and then calling them with the `await` keyword

Comment: yup not working (tested on my azure acc)have you tested on your account and it works? running on the same issue nothing is printed on re.on end

Comment: sorry not wprking

Comment: I've loaded this solution into a function in my azure account and it is printing the expected results.