# How to fix "Error: /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: invalid ELF header" on NodeJs Azure Functions in Linux?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to deploy an AzureFunctions in NodeJs but it doesn't work on Azure.
My apllication is a v3 functions running on Linux.

When the deploy is completed, i get this 500 error:

> Error:
> /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node:
> invalid ELF header

Its happen only when I do this imports:

```
 import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
 const canvasRenderService = new CanvasRenderService(width, height, chartCallback);

 const chartCallback = (ChartJS) => {
     ChartJS.register(require('chartjs-plugin-datalabels'))
 };
 const jsdom = require("jsdom");
 const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
 const { document } = (new JSDOM(`...`)).window;
```

Would someone help me please?

It works (only) on my machine :(

Edit: It works when I make the deploy by Linux Subsystem.
I hope this will help somebody.

Comment: ELF is an executable program format. You have a program/binary compiled for the wrong architecture. I do not use canvas, so I cannot advise further. https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

Answer (score 0):

**Azure function** will not include the `Node_modules` while ***deploying*** into azure. Because `Node_modules` directory contains very large file. You can include your `package.json` in you function directory and run `npm install` as you normally would with Node.js projects using **Kudu** `(https://<function_app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net )`or the **Console** in the Azure portal.

Check [Dependency management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#dependency-management) for more information.

Refer here [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58570172/15997690) & [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65871973/15997690)

Answer (score 0):

Any updates on this topic?
Doesn't seem like a valid option for me to manually run npm install via KUDU or some other terminal in a Cloud Function App - especially with Continoues Deployment etc.

Got the same problem while using canvas for barcode generation...